# Peugeot 207 convertible: "impossible to move roof: outside temperature too low"

Tags: sensor, peugeot, temperature, sunroof

My Peugeot 207 convertible from 2007 shows an error when trying to lower the roof.

**"Impossible to move roof: outside temperature too low"**

According to the manual it should be functioning down to -15 degrees and when I got the error messsage it was +9.

***Anyone seen this before?***

***Know of a simple solution?***

[image]

Thanks in advance,
/patrik

Comment: Cars these days, you aren't even free to get a cold anymore...